# how to calculate the amount of data input in android

Tags: java, android, for-loop, android-sqlite, mpandroidchart

I have a program to calculate data and display it using the **MPAndroid Chart library**, in retrieve and save data I use **SQLite Database**, because in the program that I created, the user must input numbers every day and I set setMaxValueCount for 7 days (xAxis uses date and yAxis uses float). this is my code sample:

```
public class MonitorBacaanActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

CardView btnInsert;
EditText edtData;
BarChart barChart;
database db;
long date = System.currentTimeMillis();
TextView txmonitor, txinsert;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_monitor_bacaan);

    btnInsert = findViewById(R.id.btnInsert);
    edtData = findViewById(R.id.edtData);
    barChart = findViewById(R.id.barchart);

    txmonitor = findViewById(R.id.txmonitor);
    txinsert = findViewById(R.id.txinput);
    Typeface typf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/Poppins-Medium.otf");
    txmonitor.setTypeface(typf);
    txinsert.setTypeface(typf);
    addDataGraph();
    barChart.invalidate();

    btnInsert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            saveDatabase();
        }
    });
}

public void saveDatabase(){
    db = new database(this);

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM");
    String xValue = sdf.format(date);

    String yValue = edtData.getText().toString();

    db.saveData(xValue, yValue);
    addDataGraph();
    barChart.invalidate();
    db.close();
}

public void addDataGraph(){
    db = new database(this);

    final ArrayList<BarEntry> yVal = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
    final ArrayList<String> yData = db.queryyDate();

    for (int i = 0; i < db.queryyDate().size(); i++){
        BarEntry barEntry = new BarEntry(i, Float.parseFloat(yData.get(i)));
        yVal.add(barEntry);
    }

    final ArrayList<String> xval = new ArrayList<String>();
    final ArrayList<String> xdata = db.queryxDate();

    for (int i = 0; i < db.queryxDate().size(); i++){
        xval.add(xdata.get(i));
    }

    BarDataSet dataSet = new BarDataSet(yVal, "Grafik");

    ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
    dataSets.add(dataSet);

    BarData data = new BarData(dataSets);

    barChart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(xval));

    barChart.setData(data);

    XAxis xAxis = barChart.getXAxis();

    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);

    xAxis.setAvoidFirstLastClipping(true);
    xAxis.setDrawLabels(true);
    xAxis.isCenterAxisLabelsEnabled();
    xAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true);

    YAxis yAxis = barChart.getAxisRight();
    yAxis.setEnabled(false);

    **barChart.setMaxVisibleValueCount(7);** //the maximum amount of data is displayed
    barChart.setFitBars(true);

}
```

what I want to ask is, how do you **calculate the amount of data each user inputs** and it is calculated according to the **value of barChart.setMaxVisibleValueCount (7)** and when it reaches the value limit, the data will automatically **reset** (start counting from 0)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question correctly, though, but perhaps this can help? These are used to find out the amount of data on an axis.

```
/**
* the number of entries the legend contains
*/

xAxis.mEntryCount
```

and

```
/**
* Calculates the minimum / maximum  and range values of the axis with the given
* minimum and maximum values from the chart data.
*
* @param dataMin the min value according to chart data
* @param dataMax the max value according to chart data
*/
xAxis.calculate(dataMin: Float, dataMax: Float)
```